# Adding Items to List<int> By Index Dynamically without using .Add()

Tags: c#, list

I was trying to add items to list **without** using .Add() dynamically , Please notice I cant use alternative data structures like dictionary or simple array or even a HashSet due to the nature of my project. I need a workout solution to solve the below problem as it is :

```
List<int> initA = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
     initA[i] = i;
```

**UPDATE :**
However if anyone suggests me a better datastructure to implement the following idea then I can use it as alternative :

I have set such that A for example :

```
A[0] = (1,2,3,4,5...)
A[1] = (10,20,30,40 ...)
```

and I need direct access such that : A[0][1]=2 , A[1][3]=40
I don't know what is the size of the inner array (the actual size of set elements) thats why I implement this set as Array of Lists and I cant use Jagged Array for the inner array since I don't know its size. the set elements are added at the runtime.

Any Suggestions for solving the first Issue ? or even a suggestion to replace the strategy of represent such set ?

Please notice that I need effecient data strcture since `A` will store >1M sets.

**This is very easy task in C++ where you can use pointers ... in fact this my work around for the problem since its risky to use unsafe code in C#**

Comment: This loop just sets values. Can you explain your use case?

Comment: Why do you not want to call `.Add()`? You can't do what you show, `initA[i]` only works if there's actually an element at index `i`. Looks like you could use an `int[]` array.

Comment: why can't you use `Add`?

Comment: man please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think the only way of adding items to a list **without** using `Add` is to use the constructor to do that. `new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, m))`. But it sounds strange that using any other data structure is impossible.

Comment: it is impossible. why do you want to do like that?

Comment: It's a good question. Stop down-voting. The title could be rephrased. It is about adding new items to specific indexes in a list.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about the fact that you don't know the size of the inner arrays but you know the index of the items. How do you know the index without knowing that the index is ouf of the bounds of the array. If you use the index like an identifier you can use a dictionary as inner containers that supports the functionality you want and supports adding of unsorted items.

Comment: It it easy to use pointers in C++ by using pointers without knowing the amount of elements to store? Wow. I don't know C++ as well as C# but I couldn't believe that. Where does the pointer stores the items? - No don't answer that question. I think I didn't understand your problem.

Comment: The argument with the pointers in C++ doesn't really work. You would still have to know the number of items you need. You cannot access memory that is not allocated before. And allocating when required would lead to items which are not consecutive.

Comment: @Verarind you can specify preliminary size then access only the required one with array of pointers in C++. the problem is that List does not accept such approach

Comment: You right @StefanSteinegger

Comment: @Hassan And what is the difference to using an array with preliminary size and only use the required items? Okay there is a little waste of memory but that also the case in C++. I didn't understand it - I'm out - sorry but I think I couldn't help you.

Comment: By the way, you should initialize the list with a good guess of how large it is (like `new List<int>(100000)`). It is a huge performance improvement when adding items later.

Comment: I am not following what you are trying to say @Verarind !!

Comment: @StefanSteinegger your comments have my full interest in this question, can you review the update of the question and tell me if there is a better way to represent this type of sets ?

Comment: Hard to say. Depends on whether performance or memory optimizations are more important to you. A `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>` may be an option (which uses too much memory to store the indexes, but is very easy to implement). Or the way you already started, a List<List<int>>, which is not trivial to handle. Best would be to implement you own class which manages the ints anyway, then you can easily replace the implementation with an improved implementation later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around with Dictionary:

**Usage:**

```
Vector<string> v = new Vector<string>();
v[0] = "item0";
v[10] = "item10";
string s = v[10]; //s will be "item10"
```

**Code:**

```
class Vector<T>
    {
        Dictionary<int,T> list;

        public Vector ()
        {
           this.list = new Dictionary<int,T>();
        }

        public T this [int index]{
            get
            {
                if (list.ContainsKey(index))
                    return list[index];
                else return default(T);
            }
            set {
                if (list.ContainsKey(index))
                    list[index] = value;
                else 
                    list.Add(index,value);
            }

        } 
    }
```

Comment: This is the closest I could get but still not the perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.**

A list data structure only allows you to add items with the `Add` method (or similar methods, e.g. `AddRange`). The indexer can only be used to *modify* an entry at a specific position. It cannot be used to add entries to an initially empty list.

So, you definitely need to *fill* your list before you can modify an item at a specific position, e.g.:

```
List<int> initA = new List<int>(new int[m]);
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
     initA[i] = i;
```

Note that the first line is equivalent to adding `m` zeroes in a loop, so, technically, you did not avoid "adding" items.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can't. List is concrete object with concrete behavior which cannot be simply changed.
A dirty workaround would be to pre-assign the list with default values:

```
var l = new List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(0, numberOfValuesINeed));
```

or even:

```
var l = new List<int?>(Enumerable.Repeat((int?)null, numberOfValuesINeed));
```

So you are able to figure out which values have not been assigned.

A better option would be to implement your own `IList` (using List as the internal storage would make it pretty simple if you don't mind potential O(n) inserts).

But this is all syntactic sugar, so I would either use the language as intended or use a different language that offers the dynamic behavior required. I cannot think of a none academic scenario where these constraints would apply.

Answer (score 0):

If the index is such important, you have to make sure that the element at that index actually exists or could be added.

```
List<int> initA = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
     initA.SetValueAtIndex(i, i);


public static void SetValueAtIndex<T>(this IList<T> list, int index, T value)
{
  while (list.Count <= index + 1)
  {
    list.Add(default(T));
  }
  list[index] = value;
}
```

The weakness of these code is the `.Add(default(T))` part. It adds items where the actual data isn't known. It this is not a problem in your case, don't mind. Another problem is that you could pass in a high number as index, which leads to a huge list. If this could be the case, you should definitively go with a dictionary.

Alternatively you can use an array when you know the number of items:

```
int[] initA = new int[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
     initA[i] = i;
```

Comment: **Alternatively you can use an array when you know the number of items** I dont