# How I define idbag in FluentNhibernet? Is it supported?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I would need to use idbag in fluent mappings. Is it supported in fluentnhibernet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seemed to just have ignored it. I cannot find anything in their documentation.

- There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238782/adding-items-to-listint-by-index-dynamically-without-using-add?noredirect=1#comment50476402_31238782) which proposes the use of XML
- It doesn't appear in the [Fluent mapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping)
- It doesn't appear it the [Current NHibernate Features Not Supported In Fluent](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Current-NHibernate-Features-Not-Supported-In-Fluent)

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Strange, It doesn't appear it the Current NHibernate Features Not Supported In Fluent.

Comment: I didn't see any issues, open or otherwise, about this on the Fluent NHibernate GitHub project, so I opened one: https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/issues/415.